# Measure current and consumption

Tags: arduino-uno, current

I'm trying to measure kWh with an Arduino that I have connected to a ESP8266 that communicates this value to a web server I have. And I've been trying to find the best and easiest way to go about this.

I'm thinking that I can hook a PMAC903 up to the Arduino using the interrupt pins and measuring the pulses, but I don't really know how I'm supposed to do that? Will it even work? Is this the way it's normally done? I can't really say I've found an easy solution to measure current.

You can find documentation for the PMAC903 [here](http://en.pmac.com.cn/downloadsfront.do?method=picker&flag=all&id=fba7e17b-464f-4df0-afc1-e1eeb4289986&fileId=55&isDownloadPermissions=true&memstate=/members_login.html) and I'm currently in possession of an Arduino Uno that I'm using.

Comment: You might get away with only the ESP8266, it's good enough to count pulses. The PMAC also seems to talk "Modbus-RTU protocol" RS485. I figure you're trying to measure consumption of a house and not something like the consumption/current of an LED?

Comment: [Somewhat related project](https://hackaday.io/project/10673-power-monitor-smart-meter-hack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state of this meter can be read in 3 ways:

- Pulse, this is very easy to implement. But depending on the stability of the hardware u can miss pulses leading to inaccurate values. In this way u have to calculate the meter value yourself.
- RS485, this is a communication bus not default on arduino. But given this link https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/RS485-Modules i think it is doable but not easy. This will read the value from the meter.
- M-Bus: There is special hardware needed to interact with it. This is the industry standard of doing it. It's not cheap. But u can link many meters together. This will read the value from the meter.

Depending on your time/knowledge/other requirements u have to make a chose what way your going to use.